# InfluxDB - Grant user ALL privilege on databases with certain prefix

Tags: influxdb

Title says it all. I want a specific user to have access to all databases prefixed with that user's username.

I'm using InfluxDB version 1.8.3

I've tried `GRANT ALL ON derock_% TO derock`, which results in the following error `{"error":"error parsing query: found %, expected TO at line 1, char 21"}`

I've also tried using a `*` instead of `%` to no avail.

I know enterprise has some json thing where I can do `"database": {"match": "prefix", "value": "derock" }`, but I can't seem to access the same `/role` path used for the POST request.

This is my first time diving into InfluxDB and I wasn't able to find any other posts about this. I've found ones for MySQL, but not InfluxDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc is your good friend. Especially, when you are starting: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#grant-administrative-privileges-to-an-existing-user

Doc doesn't mention, that `GRANT ALL` supports some wild chars/regexp => it's not possible. So mentioned enterprise must have implemented user matching on the application level, not on the InfluxQL level.